# jsbn.js BigInteger - how to instantiate with a normal number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, biginteger, jsbn

I tried both :

```
var a = new BigInteger(5);
```

And

```
var b = new BigInteger(5, 10);
```

But both give me the error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'b.nextBytes')
bnpFromNumberjsbn2.js:126
```

Can you only instantiate with strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd wanted to give a better answer, but you didn't mention WHICH BigInteger library you were using.

```
// Yes, use the two '..'
var a = new BigInteger(5..toString());

// Of if you have a variable
var v = 10;
var a = new BigInteger(v.toString());
```

now, with this knowledge you can override BigInteger

```
(function() {
  var oldConstructor = BigInteger;
  BigInteger = function(v) {
    if (typeof v === "number") {
      return oldConstructor(""+v);
    }
    return oldConstructor(v);
  };

}());
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps. In the title I mentioned jsbn.js but I should have added the link: http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/

Comment: Actually, looking at it, the new function should have two parameters -- but that is an easy enough fix.